Share lock between Python processes in other file
I am trying to use the multiprocessing map function to execute a function over my list. However in this function I do some API calls which can not be executed at the same time since it will overload the API. However my code is spread out over multiple files since it is quite long.
I have tried to follow to follow this solution  however it does not work for me. I suspect it does not work because I am working with more than one file. The specific error I get is: NameError: name 'lock' is not defined.
Hereby a simplyfication of my code:
main.py
import file2

def evaluate_entry_of_list(entry):
    response = file2.get_data(entry)
    # some calculations
    return results

def init_pool(given_lock):
    global lock
    lock = given_lock

if __name__ == '__main__':

    list = apicaller.get_list()
    t_lock = Lock()
    with Pool(8, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(t_lock,)) as pool:
        results = pool.map(evaluate_entry_of_list, list)
        process_results(results)

file2.py
def make_call(url, body)-> requests.Response:
    lock.acquire()
    # Make API call
    lock.release()
    return response

Other solutions I tried: defining a variable in main and import to file2 and use separate class to create static variable and import in file2.

Make a [mcve]. Don’t leave out the imports.

Each module has its own globals. lock is a global in main but you're trying to use it as a global in file2. One possible way to solve this is to put file2.lock = given_lock in init_pool. Another is to pass the lock as a parameter to make_call.

@interjay You cannot pass a multiprocessing.Lock instance as an argument to a pool worker function because you will get the cryptic error message RuntimeError: Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance.

@Booboo I didn't suggest passing it as an argument to a pool worker function.

The simple solution is to place the pool initializer function in the same module as the worker function:
file2.py
def init_pool(given_lock):
    global lock
    lock = given_lock

def make_call(url, body)-> requests.Response:
    lock.acquire()
    # Make API call
    lock.release()
    return response

file1.py

...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    list = apicaller.get_list()
    t_lock = Lock()
    with Pool(8, initializer=file2.init_pool, initargs=(t_lock,)) as pool:
        results = pool.map(evaluate_entry_of_list, list)
        process_results(results)


This worked perfectly and was a small change thank you!

There are naturally many ways to solve this type of problem, but I would suggest creating your own "pool" using Process objects instead. Things like Lock Queue, etc.. can only be passed at process creation (which is why in a pool they must be passed to the initializer). If you control the process creation it is a bit easier to pass these objects around.
Here's a demo of what that might look like (just to get an idea of how simple you can go)
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Queue, cpu_count

from api import make_call, task_list

def worker(lock, in_queue, out_queue):
    for task in iter(in_queue.get, None):
        with lock:
            out_queue.put(make_call(task))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api_lock = Lock()
    in_queue = Queue()
    out_queue = Queue()
    
    workers = [Process(target=worker, args=(api_lock, in_queue, out_queue)) for _ in range(cpu_count())]
    for worker in workers: worker.start()
    for task in task_list: in_queue.put(task)
    results = [out_queue.get() for _ in task_list]
    for _ in workers: in_queue.put(None)  # worker shutdown sentinel
    for worker in workers: worker.join()

